# SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: subquery must return only one column Using Function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I get the error "subquery must return only one column" but i tried to use differents away to return the first record when i'm selecting the curProd.

I'm using this function, but i get the the errror as far as i know in:

```
curProd := (
        SELECT "KeysForSale".*
        FROM "KeysForSale"
        WHERE row_STab.product_id = "KeysForSale".product_id AND (("KeysForSale".begin_date < payment_date AND "KeysForSale".end_date > payment_date) OR ("KeysForSale".discounted_price IS NULL))
        ORDER BY "KeysForSale".discounted_price ASC NULLS LAST
        LIMIT 1
    );
```

The all function is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION "paymentRun"(buyer_id integer, payment_date DATE, payMethod paymentMethod, paid_amount double precision, payDetails text) RETURNS VOID AS
$$
DECLARE
row_STab "SearchTable"%rowtype;
curProd  "KeysForSale"%rowtype;
totalPrice double precision;
returnedPID integer;
BEGIN

--For each entry in the search table
FOR row_STab IN 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM "SearchTable"
)
LOOP

    --We retrieve the associated product info, together with an available key
    curProd := (
        SELECT "KeysForSale".*
        FROM "KeysForSale"
        WHERE row_STab.product_id = "KeysForSale".product_id AND (("KeysForSale".begin_date < payment_date AND "KeysForSale".end_date > payment_date) OR ("KeysForSale".discounted_price IS NULL))
        ORDER BY "KeysForSale".discounted_price ASC NULLS LAST
        LIMIT 1
    );

    --Either there is no such product, or no keys for it
    IF curProd IS NULL THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Product is not available for purchase.';
    END IF;

    --Product's seller is the buyer - we can't let that pass
    IF curProd.user_id = buyer_id THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'A Seller cannot purchase their own product.';
    END IF;

    --Fill in the rest of the data to prepare the purchase
    UPDATE "SearchTable"
    SET "SearchTable".price = (
        CASE curProd.discounted_price IS NOT NULL -- if there was a discounted price, use it
        WHEN TRUE THEN curProd.discounted_price
        ELSE curProd.price
        END
        ), "SearchTable".sk_id = curProd.sk_id 
    WHERE "SearchTable".product_id = curProd.product_id;

END LOOP;

--Get total cost
totalPrice := (
    SELECT SUM("SearchTable".price)
    FROM "SearchTable"
);

--The given price does not match the actual cost?
IF totalPrice <> paid_amount THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Payment does not match cost!';
END IF;

--Create a purchase while keeping it's ID for register
INSERT INTO "Purchases" (purchase_id, final_price, user_id, paid_date, payment_method, details)
VALUES (DEFAULT, totalPrice, buyer_id, payment_date, payMethod, payDetails)
RETURNING purchase_id INTO returnedPID;

--For each product we wish to purchase
FOR row_STab IN 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM "SearchTable"
)
LOOP

    INSERT INTO "PurchasedKeys"(sk_id, purchase_id, price)
    VALUES (row_STab.sk_id, returnedPID, row_STab.price);

    UPDATE "SerialKeys"
    SET "SerialKeys".user_id = buyer_id
    WHERE row_STab.sk_id = "SerialKeys".sk_id;

END LOOP;



END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try `select "KeysForSale"` rather than `select "KeysForSale".*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the question has an incorrect answer, I'm providing an answer beyond the comment.  The code that you want is:

```
curProd := (
    SELECT "KeysForSale"
    FROM "KeysForSale"
    WHERE row_STab.product_id = "KeysForSale".product_id AND (("KeysForSale".begin_date < payment_date AND "KeysForSale".end_date > payment_date) OR ("KeysForSale".discounted_price IS NULL))
    ORDER BY "KeysForSale".discounted_price ASC NULLS LAST
    LIMIT 1
);
```

The difference is the lack of `.*`.  Your version is returning a bunch of columns -- which is the error you are getting.  You want to return a single *record*.  The table name provides this.

I also think that parentheses will have the same effect:

```
    SELECT ("KeysForSale".*)
```

Comment: Yeah, with the parentheses worked aswell!

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

For this case you should not to use syntax:

```
var := (SELECT ..).
```

Preferred should be `SELECT INTO`:

```
SELECT * INTO curProd FROM ...
```

The syntax `SELECT tabname FROM tabname` is PostgreSQL's proprietary, and although it is works well, better to not use, due unreadability for all without deeper PostgreSQL knowleadge.

Because PL/pgSQL is not case sensitive language, camel case is not advised (better to use snake case).

If it is possible, don't use ISAM style:

```
FOR _id IN
  SELECT id FROM tab1
LOOP
  SELECT * INTO r FROM tab2 WHERE tab2.id = _id
```

It is significantly slower than join (for more iterations)

```
FOR r IN
  SELECT tab2.*
    FROM tab1 JOIN tab2 ON tab1.id = tab2.id
LOOP
  ..
```

Cycles are bad for performance. This part is not really nice:

```
FOR row_STab IN 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM "SearchTable"
)
LOOP

    INSERT INTO "PurchasedKeys"(sk_id, purchase_id, price)
    VALUES (row_STab.sk_id, returnedPID, row_STab.price);

    UPDATE "SerialKeys"
    SET "SerialKeys".user_id = buyer_id
    WHERE row_STab.sk_id = "SerialKeys".sk_id;

END LOOP;
```

Possible solutions:

Use bulk commands instead:

```
INSERT INTO "PurchasedKeys"(sk_id, purchase_id, price)
   SELECT sk_id, returnedPID, price
     FROM "SearchTable"; -- using case sensitive identifiers is way to hell

UPDATE "SerialKeys"
  SET "SerialKeys".user_id = buyer_id
  FROM "SearchTable"
  WHERE "SearchTable".sk_id = "SerialKeys".sk_id;
```

The less performance of ISAM style depends on number of iterations. For low iteration it is not important, for higher number it is death.